# get json value object from mongodb

Tags: json, api, nosql

I have formData node that has dynamic jsonObject value in mongodb

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5a71fea0f36d2848ae4f8f0a"
},
"formData": {
    "pages": [
        {
            "name": "page1",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "type": "comment",
                    "name": "about",
                    "title": "Please tell us about your main requirements "
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"editorId": "59678e58f36d2842f777bc48",
"datetimeSubmit": "2018/01/15"
```

}

I write a node API to fetch the data from mongodb, it only display ids, editorI and datetimesubmit nodes, but it ignores the formData(jsondata) field.

```
const Model = require('./myModel');

module.exports = {
getData: function (callback) {

        Model.find({}, (err, jsonObj) => {

            callback(null, {
                data: jsonObj
            })
        })
}
```

}

looks like the model.find() doesn't return jsonObject value?

thanks

Comment: How are you doing this HTTP GET on MongoDB data? Are you using the Stitch JavaScript SDK, by any chance? If so, can you post the code you run on a GitHub repo or a Gist?

Answer (score 0):

got my own question fixed, basically, i should also define the data type as JSON in schema, otherwise, will be ignored.